# How to test complex RxJava Observables

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am using RxJava in my android project and I'm actually starting unit testing my code.

I have following Observable method which I'm going to test

```
private Observable<Boolean> changeMyString (@NonNull String testString) {
    return OneClass
        .doSth1(testString)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(testString2 -> Observable.create(
            subscriber -> {
                manager.setTestString2(testString2);
                AnotherClass
                    .doSth2(testString2)
                    .subscribe(
                        testString3 -> {
                            manager.setTestString3(testString3);
                            subscriber.onNext(success);
                        },
                        subscriber::onError,
                        subscriber::onCompleted
                    );
            }
        ));
```

OneClass.java doSth1(String testString)

```
private Observable<Object> doSth1 (@NonNull String testString) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            testString = "CHANGEDSTRING"
            subscriber.onNext(testString);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    });
}
```

AnotherClass.java doSth2(Object someObject)

```
    public Observable<String> doSth2 (@NonNull Object someObject) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        String changeText = preferences.getString(ANYSTRING, null); //preferences = SharedPrefences
        if (StringHelper.isEmpty(changeText)) {
            subscriber.onCompleted();
            return;
        }
        try {
            String finishedString = "WE ARE DONE! " + someObject.toString();
            subscriber.onNext(finishedString);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    });
}
```

My Test case looks like the following:

```
TestSubscriber<Boolean> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
ClassToTest.changeMyString("TESTSTRING").subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

When I debug my Code it's not reaching this part here:

```
...
.flatMap(testString2 -> Observable.create(
        subscriber -> {
            manager.setTestString2(testString2);
            AnotherClass
                .doSth2(testString2)
                .subscribe(
                    testString3 -> {
                        manager.setTestString3(testString3);
                        subscriber.onNext(success);
                    },
                    subscriber::onError,
                    subscriber::onCompleted
                );
        }
    ));
```

How can I write a Unit test for this case? I can't figure it out, why it's not working...

Thanks for your help guys!

Alban

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using directly Schedulers, you may want to inject it and use `TestScheduler` instead. It will allow your to controle executions. (as for an unit test, it may be complicated to deal with others schedulers)

For more information on the `TestScheduler` : [How to use TestScheduler in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699147/how-to-use-testscheduler-in-rxjava)

```
 class YourClass {

        private final Scheduler ioScheduler;
        private final Scheduler uiScheduler;

        public YourClass(Scheduler ioScheduler, Scheduler uiScheduler) {
               this.ioScheduler = ioScheduler;
               this.uiScheduler = uiScheduler;
        }

        private Observable<Boolean> changeMyString (@NonNull String testString) {
         return OneClass.doSth1(testString)
                        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
                        .observeOn(uiScheduler)
                        .doOnNext(str -> manager.setTestString2(str))
                        .flatMap(testString2 -> AnotherClass
                        .doSth2(testString2))
                        .doOnNext(str -> manager.setString3(str));
         }
 }
```

Then in your test, you can inject a `TestScheduler` instead :

```
   @Test
   public void example() {
          TestScheduler ui = new TestScheduler();
          TestScheduler io = new TestScheduler();
         YourClass hello = new YourClass(io, ui);
           TestSubscriber subscriber = new TestSubscriber();
           hello.changeMyString("stuff").subscribe(subscriber); 

         io.advanceByTime(2, SECONDS);
         ui.advanceByTime(2, SECONDS);

         // perform check on subscriber here
    }
```

Please note that I refactored your code as you should avoid nested subscription.

Comment: For this solution I have to change a lot of my whole project. I am using private constructors with a static method which calls the method "changeMyString()"

Comment: So your project is not modular and won't be easy to change (for example for testing purpose !). 

You still can inject a scheduler using RxPlugins but it's not recommended for testing.

Comment: I edited my question. Now you can see what my other method calls are doing. Maybe you can help me otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new Observable stream inside a onSubscribe is generally a bad idea.

You should consider something like this:

```
    OneClass
    .doSth1(testString)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(testString2 -> manager.setTestString2(testString2))
    .flatMap(testString2 -> AnotherClass.doSth2(testString2))
    .doOnNext(testString3 -> manager.setTestString3(testString3))
    .map(setTestString3 -> true);
```

From what I see in your code, this should give you what you want.

Comment: This one is not working. It is not calling the "AnotherClass.doSth2(testString2)"-method.... I really don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Ho, isn't it ? are you sure OneClass.doSth1(...) is emitting at least one item ?
Maybe you provide us with what those methods are doing ?

Comment: I edited my question so you see what the methods are doing