# RxJava and unit testing with mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, tdd, rx-java, mosby

I wanna test my Presenter

```
public class MainPresenter extends MvpBasePresenter<MainView> {

    private Repository repository;

    private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    public void setRepository(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void loadFromRepository() {
        getView().showLoading(false);

        disposables.add(repository.getCountries()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Country>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Country> countries) {
                        if (isViewAttached()) {
                            getView().setData(countries);
                            getView().showContent();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        if (isViewAttached()) {
                            getView().showError(e, false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                }));
    }

    public void loadFromRemoteDatastore() {
        disposables.add(new RemoteDataStore().getCountries()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Country>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Country> countries) {
                        if (isViewAttached()) {
                            getView().setData(countries);
                            getView().showContent();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        if (isViewAttached()) {
                            getView().showError(e, false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                }));
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView(boolean retainInstance) {
        super.detachView(retainInstance);
        if (!retainInstance) {
            disposables.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have many doubts, what's the best way to test it

1) Is this alright if I will write these 4 test scenarios

```
shouldShowContentWhenLoadFromRepository()
shouldShowErrorWhenLoadFromRepository()
shouldShowContentWhenLoadFromRemoteDatastore()
shouldShowErrorWhenLoadFromRemoteDatastore()
```

2) Should I write a test for detachView(boolean retainInstance) and clear disposables

3) What kind of mechanisms are the best in my case to test RxJava?

Comment: Does your MainPresenter have any non void methods to the outside? If you want to test the behaviour of your Presenter you would need a stream of Events, like LoadingDataFailedEvent, which you could subscribe to from outside and test it, if mocked repository return Obs.error().

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Hans. I posted my whole Presenter, I have only void methods. Don't get it, to be honest. By any chance, could you write sample code, post a link to any open source code or article that explains what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. Those test scenarios seem reasonable.
2. It's often good practice to have tests covering an object's public surface, but testing that `detachView()` clears `disposables` may be tricky given the current implementation of `MainPresenter`.
3. You could create a stub for `Repository` the returns an Observable returned when `GetCountries()` is called. You can create both successful and unsuccessful Observables by using `Observable.return()` & `Observable.error()` respectively.

If you need more control over the specific timing of the asynchrony the `TestScheduler` makes it very simple [(seen
    here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26699940/8934475).